# Detailed definition of the Monotone Convergence Theorem

Tags: probability, convergence

I have a basic definition of the Monotone Convergence Theorem:

> If $\{X_n\}_{n\geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of random variables such that $X_n\nearrow X$ **pointwise** and $X_n\geqslant 0\ \forall n$, then $E(X_n)\nearrow E(X)$.

My question , how much liberality can made on the convergence part? I mean: which of these (namely - **almost sure** convergence , convergence **in probability**, $\&$ convergence **in distribution**) can be placed in place of the **pointwise** convergence and still the definition remains exactly same?

Answer (score 1):

It is also true under the convergence in distribution if we replace the assumption of non-decresingness by stochastic dominance, that is, $\left(\mathbb P\left\{X_n\gt t\right\}\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$ is non-increasing for any $t$. Indeed, we have
$$\mathbb E\left[X_n\right]=\int_0^{+\infty}\Pr\left\{X_n\gt t\right\}\mathrm dt, $$
$\Pr\left\{X_n\gt t\right\}\to \Pr\left\{X\gt t\right\}$ for $\lambda$-almost every $t$ (by convergence in distribution) and $\Pr\left\{X_n\gt t\right\}\uparrow \Pr\left\{X\gt t\right\}$. The result thus follows by an application of the monotone convergence theorem, which works when the pointwise convergence is replaced by the almost sure convergence.

Comment: You mean if $X_n $ increasingly converges **in distribution** to $X$, then $E(X_n)\nearrow E(X)$ ?

Comment: @Qwerty Yes, this is what is mean.

Comment: To be frank, can you please provide me with an example of a sequence $X_n$ increasingly converging to $X$ in distribution? My head has just gone blank right now! I need to do certain things to convince myself..